# lock performance in 2 different scenarios

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

I have a class with 2 inline lists containing more than 1000 element like this,

```
public class A
{
    private List<long> aList = new List<long>();
    private List<long> bList = new List<long>();
    void MethodThatUsesAList()
    {
      //Works with aList
    }
    void MethodThatUsesBList()
    {
      //Works with bList
    }
    void MethodThatUsesBoth()
    {
      //Works with both lists
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make this class thread safe, and there are 2 different scenarios I see using locks, first to create

```
object _synchObject = new object()
```

and lock this object in all methods, 
or second to lock each list when it is being used, 
My first question is , which method is preferred?
and in case of second is preferred, is it performance issue to use lock like this?

```
    void MethodThatUsesBoth()
    {
       lock(aList){
           lock(bList){
                 //Works with both lists
           }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate questions here:

- Whether to use one combined lock or two separate locks
- Whether to use separate objects to lock on or the lists themselves (or their `SyncRoot`s)

These are separable to some extent - in that if you're using two separate locks you can create two separate objects to lock on, one for each list.

If you want `MethodThatUsesAList` and `MethodThatUsesBList` to be able to run concurrently, you'll need two separate locks. You'll then have to make sure that any time you might acquire both locks, you acquire them in the same order. That means reasoning about all the code within any method which acquires a lock: you'll need to make sure that it doesn't call *another* method which acquires the other lock, for example.

If your particular scenario isn't likely to suffer much from *all* the methods effectively being blocked for other threads by any one thread running *any* of them, then I'd use a single lock just for simplicity.

In either case, I'd personally go for "private" locks which no other code knows about. I find it easier to reason about code written that way. Using the list itself or the sync root may well be absolutely fine - but I just prefer to think about locks which nothing else can possibly acquire.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MethodThatUsesBoth()
{
   lock(((ICollection)aList).SyncRoot){
       lock(((ICollection)bList).SyncRoot){
             //Works with both lists
       }
   }
}
void MethodThatUsesAList()
{
   lock(((ICollection)aList).SyncRoot){

   }
}
void MethodThatUsesBList()
{
   lock(((ICollection)bList).SyncRoot){

   }
}
```

In other your solution, i think is this not good because you blocking access to bList when you working only on aList. This is not good performance solution.

Comment: In my app Lists are dictionaries unfortunately, I changed to List for making simple

Answer (score 0):

In general the former (an otherwised unused mutex) is preferred I believe. No real cost to do so, and too easy to get the latter wrong, too easy to create deadlocks.

Comment: but mutex is slower than monitor(in other words lock) in .net, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean the literal Sysytem.Threading.Mutex class, just the logical concept. My bad for the confusion.